# regex to parse xml string

Tags: java, regex

I have a pom.xml file which I convert into string and trying to parse the dependencies it. For example

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
  </dependency>    
</dependencies>
```

I am trying to get the content between the `dependency` tag using the pattern

```
({<}dependency{>}.*?{</}dependency{>})
```

My goal is to get all the text like.

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
```

What is the correct pattern to do this ?

Comment: why not use a proper xml library?

Comment: regexps are just the wrong tool to parse XML. You will never be able to process all cases correctly (think of comments, spaces, newlines, CDATA sections, ...)

Comment: @Henry is right go for other methods like unmarshaller in java

Comment: yes there are library which I will look at but I am wondering why am I getting no matches with the pattern that I am using. I expected that the pattern should return some match atleast

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<dependency>(.*?)</dependency>", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

`Pattern.DOTALL` - is a modifier to match the dot for newline characters.

Comment: @Pavneet Singh It works in EditPad. There might be some specifics, like extra escaping characters for `/`. In general this is a correct approach.Simple regex for a multiline string.
In PHP you have a modifier `s` for that. In EditPad you enable the "Dot" mode. In Java `Pattern.DOTALL`. Etc.

Comment: i know it will work though it would have been great if you also mentioned about using `matcher.group(1)`